# Client cert using postman and curl

Tags: curl, postman, mtls

As part of mTLS, we are required to provide client certificate to the server while making a REST connection.
If I look at the **curl** request this is how the syntax looks

```
curl -v --cert cert.crt --key key.key --pass foobar https://testserver/soap/request
```

and this is where we specify client certificate in the **postman**

[image]

I'm trying to understand the ***role of client's private key in mTLS***. Here are my questions

1. Why are we using the private key in the curl request? Does that flow through the https? Isn't the private key meant to be secret?
2. Is private key a required parameter? Can we make curl request without using the private key? Is that a valid request? At least works fine in postman if I only add the cert.
3. How is the request being made by curl different from postman where we aren't providing any private key?

Comment: Curl requires the certificate's private key. That is the `--key key.key` argument. The client certificate private key is required for mTLS to generate a signature for the CertificateVerify message during the TLS handshake.

Comment: @JohnHanley What about postman? It's an option field there, right?

Comment: The private key is not optional for mTLS. I do not use Postman, but make sure that mTLS is actually used if the field is optional. It might default to standard TLS.

Comment: @JohnHanley the server I'm communicating requires mTLS and it works fine only if I provide client cert through postman.

Comment: The private key is not optional for mTLS. That means something else is going on. Review the spec for mTLS: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8705